# Group by using the Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, group-by, igrouping

I receive 48 files per day on a half hourly basis from market. These files have a start time as a property. I am using Entity Framework to view these files in a web application and as the files have a UK time but I am working with a european market the trading day begins the day before at 11pm and so I want to group these together based on the trading day.

In SQL I can accomplish this by:

```
select cast(DATEADD(hour, 1, START_TIME) as date), count(cast(START_TIME as date)) 
from imbalancecost
group by cast(DATEADD(hour, 1, START_TIME) as date)
```

I am trying to achieve a similar result in C# using the following attempt:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<DateTime, ImbalanceCost> imbalanceCost = db.ImbalanceCost.GroupBy(ic => ic.START_TIME).ToArray();
```

Is there any means of first adding the hour onto my grouping and then using only the date part of this new calculated value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any means of first adding the hour onto my grouping and then using only the date part of this new calculated value?

In LINQ to Entities (EF6) it's a matter of using respectively the canonical functions [`DbFunctions.AddHours`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.addhours(v=vs.113).aspx) and [`DbFunctions.TruncateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.truncatetime(v=vs.113).aspx):

```
db.ImbalanceCost.GroupBy(ic => 
    DbFunctions.TruncateTime(DbFunctions.AddHours(ic.START_TIME, 1)).Value)
```

Note that `.Value` (or cast to `DateTime`) is to make the result `DateTime` rather than `DateTime?` returned by the canonical method in case `ic.START_TIME` is not nullable, hence you know the result is not nullable as well.

Comment: Perfect Ivan this is what I needed. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to add an hour to the start time and group by the date part. That can be done as follows:

```
var imbalanceCost = db.ImbalanceCost
    .Select(x => EntityFunctions.AddHours(x.START_TIME, 1))
    .GroupBy(ic => ic.Value.Date)
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Does not recognize the method System.DateTime.AddHours(Double) method, and this cmethod cannot be translated into a stored expression

Comment: @Jay Oops, I forgot you are on Entity Framework and not Core, try with my edit

Comment: ic.Date is now throwing an error that DateTime? does not contain a definition for date